# Closing connection in HikariPool

Tags: java, jdbc, hikaricp

I have a standalone java application that gets streams of messages, batches and inserts them to a SQL Server database using Hikaricp.

Currently what I do is the following:

- Get a connection from the pool.
- Create a prepared statement to insert using the connection
- Execute the batch insert.

Note that I never close the connection! And once I reach the maxPoolSize (20), I get an error when I tried to get a new connection.

Should I be closing the connection after every batch insert?

- Get a connection from the pool.
- Create a prepared statement to insert using the connection
- Execute the batch insert.
- **Close the prepared statement & connection.**

However, this means that I am incurring the cost of getting a connection from the pool + creating a new prepared statement after every batch insert.

Is this the recommended approach or are there any alternatives which can reduce this extra cost?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to close connection. usually pools return connections wrapped into another object. And when you call `close` on wrapper it simply marks internal database connection as free and returns it to the pool.

Also you can reuse existing `PreparedStatement` objects if they are the same. If each of your tasks has to use its unique `PreparedStatement` (due to your business logic) then there is no other way and you have to create new `PreparedStatement` for each task.

Comment: Thank you Ivan. The query I execute in the PreparedStatement doesn't change. However, since it is associated with Connection (connection.prepareStatement(query), can I still reuse it if I close the connection it was used to create?

Comment: You need to close and recreate since `PreparedStatement` is linked to a `Connection`